# windows azure or IIS slow in inital load

Tags: iis, azure, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a simple personal MVC4 web app that is hosted in Windows Azure.

This web app is very minimal in use, the initial call is very slow specially when I tried to click in the morning.

I’m suspecting that the IIS is sleeping and need to wake up. I found this article and mention that this is a bug in IIS http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/8b3258e7-261c-49a0-888c-0b3e68b2af13 which required setting up in IIS but my web app is hosted in Azure, is there any way to do some sort of setting in Web.config file?

All succeeding calls are fast.

Here is my personal page. [javierdelacruz.com](http://javierdelacruz.com)

Thanks.

Comment: See Force Application Start on Azure Web Role:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238569/force-application-start-on-azure-web-role/14261645#14261645

Would've put this in as an Answer, but some bug in the site keeps posting it as a comment instead.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. Startup Tasks
2. OnStart Code

For startup tasks, see [this link](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/controlling-application-pool-idle-timeouts-in-windows-azure).

For OnStart code, try a function like this (this function does a few more things, too):

```
    private const string _web_app_project_name = "Web";

    public static void SetupDefaultEgConfiguration(int idleTimeoutInMinutes = 1440, int recycleTimeoutInMinutes = 1440, string appPoolName = "My Azure App Pool", bool enableCompression = true)
    {
        if (!RoleEnvironment.IsEmulated)
        {
            Trace.TraceWarning("Changing IIS settings upon role's OnStart. Inputs: ({0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", idleTimeoutInMinutes, recycleTimeoutInMinutes, appPoolName, enableCompression);

            // Tweak IIS Settings
            using (var iisManager = new ServerManager())
            {
                try
                {
                    var roleSite = iisManager.Sites[RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id + "_" + _web_app_project_name];
                    if (enableCompression)
                    {
                        //================ Enable or disable static/Dynamic compression ===================//
                        var config = roleSite.GetWebConfiguration();
                        var urlCompressionSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/urlCompression");
                        urlCompressionSection["doStaticCompression"] = true;
                        urlCompressionSection["doDynamicCompression"] = true;
                        Trace.TraceWarning("Changing IIS settings to enable static and dynamic compression");
                    }

                    //================ To change ApplicationPool name ================================//
                    var app = roleSite.Applications.First();
                    app.ApplicationPoolName = appPoolName;

                    //================ To change ApplicationPool Recycle Timeout ================================//
                    var appPool = iisManager.ApplicationPools[app.ApplicationPoolName];
                    appPool.Recycling.PeriodicRestart.Time = new TimeSpan(0, recycleTimeoutInMinutes, 0);

                    //================ idletimeout ====================================================//               
                    var defaultIdleTimeout = iisManager.ApplicationPoolDefaults.ProcessModel.IdleTimeout;
                    var newIdleTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, idleTimeoutInMinutes, 0);
                    if ((int)newIdleTimeout.TotalMinutes != (int)defaultIdleTimeout.TotalMinutes)
                    {
                        appPool.ProcessModel.IdleTimeout = newIdleTimeout;
                    }

                    // Commit the changes done to server manager.
                    iisManager.CommitChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Trace.TraceError("Failure when configuring IIS in Azure: " + e.ToString().Take(63000));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[Source and some more details](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sriharsha/archive/2012/04/07/how-to-increase-application-pool-idletimeout-in-windows-azure-cloud-applications.aspx) for the function I included here - there are some dependencies you'll likely need to accomplish this.