# Configuring httpCompression settings for WIndows Azure Web Sites

Tags: azure, http-compression

Is there anyway of controlling the compression settings in windows azure web sites.

I want to enable dynamic json compression, and can successfully do this with on premise sites by configuring the applicationHosts.config file accordingly.

Are there any options for doing this on a windows azure web site? (not web role)

Comment: See the following link where I answered another question. I'm not sure if this will work with "Azure Web Sites" but it does work with Web Roles. Note that his question is different but my solution handles both his and your questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387986/windows-azure-or-iis-slow-in-inital-load/14388428#14388428

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTP compression is not supported with Windows Azure Websites. As this is a very common request from Windows Azure Websites, so Azure Websites team does know about it and working on it. If HTTP compression is MUST for your application, I would say Azure Web Role is your best option.

Comment: See Nir's reply relating to this support coming to WAWS.

Comment: HTTP compression for Windows Azure web sites is now available as of the January, 2014 Azure release.

Comment: STL Developer, the answer I gave in 2013 which was correct that time, commenting an old correct answer as -ve does not justify your -ve comment.

Comment: @AvkashChauhan - Of course it does.  Otherwise when someone turns this up on SO thinking it's the correct answer (since it's the selected answer), they may not realize their mistake.  Why don't you consider updating your answer to reflect current reality?

Answer (score 4):

As of the January 2014 Windows Azure release, Azure web sites now fully support HTTP compression, among several other unlocked features.

For an excellent MS blog article on this from the Windows Azure Team Blog, please see this:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2014/01/28/more-to-explore-configuration-options-unlocked-in-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx

Answer (score 1):

HTTP compression in IIS is enabled through ApplicationHost.config. We will enable access to this section in WAWS in our October release (exact date TBD). In the October release this will be enabled through a special file users will have to upload (we will provide documentation when we release). Later on (December or January release) we will enable this section in the application web.config. Configuration reference: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpcompression